# Multiple parameters in Coldfusion MYSQL Connection String Not Being Recognised

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, mysql-connector, coldfusion-2021

I am trying to add the following two parameters to a Coldfusion MySQL DSN connection string:

```
allowMultiQueries=TRUE
autocommit=FALSE
```

When I add either one parameter to the connection string as a single parameter connection string, the setting is picked up fine in Coldfusion.
For example `allowMultiQueries=TRUE` works and allows multiple queries to be processed. Alternatively `autocommit=FALSE` disables autocommits as expected.

However, combining both parameters in the connection string saves without error in the CF Admin when updating the DSN, but ignores the last parameter when my code is run.
Example of that connection string: `allowMultiQueries=TRUE&autocommit=FALSE`

So in this example, the autocommit parameter is ignored and I get a CF error:

```
An exception occurred when committing the transaction.
The root cause of this exception was: java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true.
```

Why is Coldfusion not recognising the second parameter? I tried delimiting the variables with a ; instead of an & but that threw an error when trying to save the datasource and wouldn't allow it.

This is for Coldfusion 2021.0.03.329779 and MYSQL 8.0.23 using the mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar file (recommended as later version had other known bugs with datetime types)

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the `{CF Instance Name}\lib\neo-datasource.xml` and see how the file has the values set for connection string and post the line here?

Comment: Sure, this is what the xml parameter is set at:
`<string>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hugirls?tinyInt1isBit=false&amp;allowMultiQueries=TRUE&amp;autocommit=FALSE</string>`

Comment: (Edit) Where did you see `autocommit` as a url parameter in the documentation? I don't see a [property](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/core-api/java/com/mysql/cj/conf/PropertyKey.java) by that name. Also, even if upper case true/false work, it's a good habit to assume anything java is case sensitive and copy the case is used in any examples. ie. `allowMultiQueries=true`

Comment: How are you confirming `autocommit=FALSE` works? Adding that single setting to a CF2018 DSN / MySQL 8.0.12 / 8.0.22 connector jar didn't disable auto commit for me.